# Ajax Datatable not searching properly with datepicker

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, datatable

I'm building a function in Laravel along with the datatables and ajax. I have a fully working page with multiple functions that return data into the databale however one of the functions doesn't like to search properly and doesn't return any data into the table.

I have a datapicker with the following code:

```
<div class=" input-group mb-3">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
         <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i></span>
    </div>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" data-plugin-datepicker id="lastLogged" name="lastLogged" placeholder="Owner has not logged in since:">
</div>
```

My search button is called: search_data

My ajax call is as followed:

```
<script>
$(document).on("click", "#search_data", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).html("<i class='fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin'></i>");
    })

    $.ajax({
        url: "/search/user",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
        data: {
            loginUser : $('#lastLogged').val()
        }
    })

    .done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        table.ajax.reload();
        $('#search_data').html('<i class="fas fa-search"></i>');
    })
    .fail(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $('#search_data').html('<i class="fas fa-search"></i>');
    });
});
```

My PHP controller:

```
public function Building(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) 
    {           
        $buildings = building::with('ownerinfo');
        $data = array();
        $totalData = building::count();
        $totalFiltered = $totalData; 
        $start = $request->input('start');
        $order = 'id';
        $dir = $request->input('order.0.dir'); 

        // Other if statements here with functions

        if(isset($request->login))
        {
            $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($request->login));
            $users = Users::where('last_login_in', '<=', $date)->get();
            foreach($users as $user) {

            $buildings = $buildings->where('owner', $user->id);
            }
        }

        $buildings = $buildings->get(); 
        if(!empty($buildings))
        {
            foreach ($building as $building)
            {
                $nestedData['id'] = $building->id;
                $nestedData['name'] = $building->buildingName;
                $nestedData['view'] = '<a class="button is-small full-width is-hovered" href="/view/building/' . $building->id . '">View</a>';
                $data[] = $nestedData;
            }

            $json_data = array( 
                "data" => $data,
                "draw"            => intval($request->input('draw')),  
                "recordsTotal"    => intval($totalData),
                "recordsFiltered" => intval($totalFiltered)
            );
            return json_encode($json_data);
        }
    }
}
```

This keeps on returning no data at all. I am using 1 January 2019 from the datepicker to search, it has the value: 2019-01-01 00:00:00 and the data of one of the users in the database has 2018-08-20 07:11:34. I checked the queries with var_dumps and it returns the correct users, however it doesn't show any results in the buildings datatable.

The idea behind this is to let an administrator select a specific date, the database runs the search and returns buildings of users that have not logged in since the selected date.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `$users` return the correct users but the `$buildings` are empty?
Try to use a `hasMany` relation between the User and Building it will be a better solution than this:

`foreach($users as $user) {
     $buildings = $buildings->where('owner', $user->id);
}`